# How to enable swiping on all 4 directions in the Dismissible Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am building a *puzzle* app in Flutter and I am using the **Dismissible** inside a **GridView** to detect swipes on the tiles of the puzzles.

The problem is, I can dismiss a widget either in `left-right` or `up-down` direction at a time.

Is there a way to to enable all the four directions?

This is the function that returns the Dismissible:

```
  Dismissible getPiece(Piece piece) {
    return Dismissible(
      direction: DismissDirection.horizontal,
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        print(direction);
      },
      key: UniqueKey(),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: pieceColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
              spreadRadius: 0,
              blurRadius: 3,
              offset: const Offset(0, 2),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            value,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: valueColor, fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to to enable all the four directions?"* - no, to do that you need to write your own custom widget

Comment: Ohh is there any other widget similar to Dismissible?

Comment: i dont think so, simply copy [dismissible.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/db747aa133/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/dismissible.dart) to your project, rename `Dismissible` to `MyDismissible` or something and remove [direction](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/db747aa133/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/dismissible.dart#L153) property

Comment: I will do that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pskink suggested, you cannot swipe on all four directions by default so you can create your own widget or create a copy of `Dismissible`.

Here's what you can change to achieve swipe on all 4 directions.

First, copy the `dismissible.dart` file to your project and rename `Dismissible` to any name of your choice - `MyDismissible` for example.

Create a new `DismissibleDirection` - `all` for example,

```
enum DismissDirection {
  vertical,
  horizontal,
  endToStart,
  startToEnd,
  up,
  down,
  none,
  all,
}
```

Then you need to change only a few more things at the end of the dismissible.dart.

If the `dismiss direction is all`, we get the direction of swipe from `GestureDetector`. If it is *vertical*, the set direction to `DismissDirection.vertical` and if it's *horizontal*, set it to `DismissDirection.horizontal`.

```
if (widget.direction == DismissDirection.none) {
  return content;
}

// THIS IS THE EXTRA IF THAT IS TO BE ADDED
if (widget.direction == DismissDirection.all) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onHorizontalDragStart: ((details) {
      widget.direction = DismissDirection.horizontal;
      _handleDragStart(details);
    }),
    onHorizontalDragUpdate: _handleDragUpdate,
    onHorizontalDragEnd: _handleDragEnd,
    onVerticalDragStart: ((details) {
      widget.direction = DismissDirection.vertical;
      _handleDragStart(details);
    }),
    onVerticalDragUpdate: _handleDragUpdate,
    onVerticalDragEnd: _handleDragEnd,
    behavior: widget.behavior,
    dragStartBehavior: widget.dragStartBehavior,
    child: content,
  );
}

return GestureDetector(
  onHorizontalDragStart: _directionIsXAxis ? _handleDragStart : null,
  onHorizontalDragUpdate: _directionIsXAxis ? _handleDragUpdate : null,
  onHorizontalDragEnd: _directionIsXAxis ? _handleDragEnd : null,
  onVerticalDragStart: _directionIsXAxis ? null : _handleDragStart,
  onVerticalDragUpdate: _directionIsXAxis ? null : _handleDragUpdate,
  onVerticalDragEnd: _directionIsXAxis ? null : _handleDragEnd,
  behavior: widget.behavior,
  dragStartBehavior: widget.dragStartBehavior,
  child: content,
);
```

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks!!